# How can I detect if textbox has text?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, textbox, storyboard

I have a textbox which has an animation but i want it to stop that animation if the textbox has text and start again if the textbox doesn't have text? But i'm not sure if this is possible as the animation is linked to another textbox?

TextBoxStyle1 is the animation.

TextBoxStyle2 is where the text input will be.

Here is my code;

```
 <Window.Resources>

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <local:TextInputToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextInputToVisibilityConverter" />

    <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardBorder">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFABADB3"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="#FF00BCD4"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>


    <FontFamily x:Key="MainFont">Arial</FontFamily>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FFC1C1C1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF00BCD4"/>


    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFont}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardTextAnimation">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-23.333"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.76"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.76"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-25.597"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF8B8B8B"/>
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF00BCD4"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardTextAnimation_Copy1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-23.333"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.76"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.76"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-25.597"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF00BCD4"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FFC1C1C1"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Border x:Name="border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="TextBox" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="Floating Label Text" Background="White" Margin="0,3.75,0,3.25">
                            <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>


                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />


                        </Trigger>


                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
         Value="True">

                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardBorder}" />
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardTextAnimation}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>

                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardTextAnimation_Copy1}" />
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>

                        </DataTrigger>


                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkForeground" Color="LightGray" />


    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border2" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyleNew" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardAnimateText"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Margin="0,-5,0,0">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border2}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="0"/>

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border3" Color="#FF00BCD4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border2" Color="#FF00BCD4"/>


    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>


                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>



</Window.Resources>



<Grid Name="grid1" Focusable="True">

    <Grid x:Name="TextBoxes" Margin="23.75,0,-23.75,0">
        <TextBlock Margin="250.449,182.112,374.044,0"   Text="Hint Text" Foreground="{StaticResource brushWatermarkForeground}"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Height="19.725" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
        <TextBox Name="txtUserEntry"  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1" Margin="250.449,182.112,352.952,0" Height="25.689" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle2}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="Floating Label Text"   Height="25.689" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="250.449,182.112,352.952,0" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="#FFC1C1C1" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: did you tried textBox1.text ?

Comment: Why has this been marked down? I'm new to this so i'm sorry if my question is not brilliant. I did yes but it didn't work.

Comment: @WalterM it's not stupid, it's just unclear on what TextBox style he wants to refer. He has 2 TextBox styles and I've just found out there is just TextBox style 1 involved. This question is very close to a perfect question, it's just unclear. It should of course haven't been downvoted much like that.

Comment: Note that he may want to do this in ***XAML***, not in code. And I'm sure not every one knows how to do this in XAML.

Comment: He is she lol .. Anyway I did not realise this was possible in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the down votes, as solving this would have been a good exercise for anyone looking to hone their WPF style/template skills.

There are two important things to remember when creating styles/templates, especially when triggers get involved.

1. The order of the triggers matters.
2. If you find yourself scratching your head, you need to look at it from another angle and simplify.

At the point where you got, it would have been a good time to go ahead and make a [custom control](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html), in fact the example I provide below is going to be just that.

For what you are attempting to do, you have 3 possible outcomes to test for. If we take a few steps back and look, we can see exactly what we need to do, I'll break it down.

1. IsFocused

   - Color the border and label *(This happens no matter what)*
2. !IsFocused & Text.Length = 0

   - ENTER: Lower and resize the label.
   - EXIT: Raise and resize the label.
3. IsFocused & Text.Length = 0

   - ENTER: Display the hint.
   - EXIT: Hide the hint.

That's it, those are the only three triggers that we need, one Trigger and two MultiTriggers. You could get creative and make it only one trigger really, but maintainability and readability would be horrendous.

Let's start with the code for the custom control:

```
public class AnimatedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof (string), typeof (AnimatedTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HintProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Hint", typeof (string), typeof (AnimatedTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    static AnimatedTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (AnimatedTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (AnimatedTextBox)));
    }

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Hint
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(HintProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HintProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I've just made Label and Hint strings to keep things simple, you could make them objects and expand the possibilities some.

And now the style:

```
<Color x:Key="Color.Control.Border.Focus">#FF00BCD4</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush.Control.Border" Color="#FFABADB3" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidColorBrush.Hint" Color="LightGray" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatedTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SolidColorBrush.Control.Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatedTextBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources />
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LabelTextBlock"
                                       Focusable="False"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Label}">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".75" ScaleY=".75" />
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                              Focusable="false"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="HintTextBlock"
                                           Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                           Focusable="False"
                                           Foreground="{StaticResource SolidColorBrush.Hint}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Opacity="0"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Hint}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"
                                                        To="{StaticResource Color.Control.Border.Focus}" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                        To="{StaticResource Color.Control.Border.Focus}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                         To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                         To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                                         To="15" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="HintTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To="1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="HintTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The style is 95% what you had, I just combined it into one control. The only thing I really changed, was I set up the template to be defaulted in the 'IsFocused' and 'HasText' state. The idea is that our control always strives to be in that state, so it's easier to trip it up and set it to the other state. There are a few more ifs and buts the other way around, so coding for the least-common denominator plays to our benefit.

The usage would be as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <local:AnimatedTextBox Width="300"
                               Margin=" 0 0 0 15"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Hint="Hint 1"
                               Label="Label 1" />
        <local:AnimatedTextBox Width="300"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Hint="Hint 2"
                               Label="Label 2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

It may not be perfect, but hopefully that gets you on the right track.